# Software Updater update failed

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, qt

When I'm trying to update all packages in my environment, using GUI or from terminal by :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get :
[image: http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt-5.11.1-xenial/ubuntu bionic Release not found]

It simple says :

```
...
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt-5.11.1-xenial/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
...
```

Using the GUI, I get :
[image: software updater repo info fetch failed]

But it exists : http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt-5.11.1-xenial/ubuntu/

Comment: Why are you adding a `xenial` ppa to a `bionic` system?

Answer (score 0):

yes, the ppa exist but it "supports" until Ubuntu Xenial, while you're on bionic, so it will never work